# Deriving an adjacency matrix wrt distance

Tags: python, numpy

Let's suppose that I have `n` points, and a square numpy matrix where `i,j`'th entry is filled with the distance between the point `i` and point `j`. How can I derive an adjacency matrix in a way that, there is an "edge" between point `a` and point `b` if for every other point `c`, `max(dist(c,a), dist(c,b)) > dist(a,b)`, in other words there is not any other point `c` such as `c` is closer to `a` and `b` than, `a` and `b` are to each other. I could write this in numpy with some for loops, but I wonder if there is any easier/faster way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really hard to do without a concrete example, so I may be getting this slightly wrong.

So you have an nxn matrix (presumably symmetric with a diagonal of 0) representing the distances.  Let's call this matrix A.

Then `A[:,None,:]` is an nx1xn matrix such that if you broadcast it to nxnxn, then `A[i, j, k]` is the distance from the i'th point to the k'th point.  Likewise, `A[None, :, :]`, when broadcast to nxnxn, gives a matrix such that `A[i, j, k]` gives the distance from the j'th point to the kth point.

So `B = np.maximum(A[:,None,:],A[None,:,:])` is an array such at `b[i, j, k]` is the maximum of the distance from i to k or from j to k.  Take the minimum of B along the last dimension, and you've got the value for the best possible `k`.  Edges are those values for which `np.min(B, axis=2) <= A.`

Again, try this out on your own computer.  I may have slight details wrong.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run B = max(A[:,None,:],A[None,::]) : The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Fixed two typos.  There should be a comma between the ::.  Also dimensions are zero-based so axis=2.

Comment: actually I added the comma myself when I tried but still the same error

Comment: np.maximum works tho. I'll try and see if it solves my question

Comment: Sorry.  I woke in the middle of the night and realized I should have used np.max.   I don't think np.maximum takes an `axis` array.

Comment: Sorry.  I should have known better than to type np code without entering into the computer first.  `np.maximum` to take the maximum element from each of two arrays.  `np.min` to allow you to take the minimum of an array along an axis.  The explanation is fine.  Just I wrote it down incorrectly at 11pm.